# How do I submit a form using jQuery after AJAX validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My form has one input which needs to be validated before submitting. After a successful validation I try to submit the form, but it doesn't submit.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function () {
        checkInputData();
        return false;  // to prevent default submit
    });
});
```

The validation function:

```
function checkInputData() {
    var id = $($("#id")).val();  // value, which needs to be validated
    $.get("check.php?id=" + id,  
        function(result){  
            if(result == 1) {  
                //if the result is 1, need to submit
                $("#myForm").unbind(); // to prevent recursion?
                $("#myForm").submit(); // doesnt work
            } else {  
                // dont submit, give some visual feedback, etc...
            }  
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: Why not do the validation when the form is submitted instead of making two trips to the server? Your validation method, as it stands, could be defeated unless you revalidate on form submit anyway.

Comment: no errors in console.   
need to validate before submitting, because the form submits large images.

Comment: ok try to check for the returning result maybe you are missing something(it happens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the result from your AJAX validation request. You can do this by setting this check to being `async: false`, this means the `checkInputData()` will wait for the result to come back, and you can return it, controlling the submission of the form.

In your code it's not waiting for the `$.get` action to happen, and it appears to skip over meaning your code will always appear to `return true;` from the `checkInputData()` call. You don't need to `return false` in submit, if used as below.

I have used the `$.ajax` call in place of `$.get` because it allows you to control the `async` property, but it essentially does the same thing. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
function checkInputData() {
    var value = $("#id").val();  // Value to be validated
    var passedValidation = false;
    $.ajax("check.php?id=" + value, {
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            // Do whatever check of the server data you need here.
            if(result == "1") {  
                // Good result, allow the submission
                passedValidation = true;
            } else {
                // Show an error message
            }
        }
    });
    return passedValidation;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").on("submit", function () {
        return checkInputData();
    });
});
```

I assume you have a button such as below, within your form with id `myForm`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Comment: This is working. async: false is the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Additional people reading this: This is bad advice, don't ever do this - this will hang the browser while waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting submitted may be because you are not returning `1` on successful validation for `result` in below `if condition`

```
if(result == 1) {
```

In `check.php` your output should be 1, like `echo '1';` if input is valid. And make sure there is not any other output before or after it.

Answer (score 0):

AMember is correct your always returning false, there are a few solution. One solution is for you to bind your validation to a button element or any element that will not submit the form.

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
   .
   input elements
   .
   <button class= "submit" type="button" onclick="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Document Ready

```
$(function() 
{
   var $submit = $(".submit");

   $submit.click(function () 
   {
     checkInputData();

   });
});
```

Validation Callback Function

```
function checkInputData() 
{
   var id = $('#id').val();  // value, which needs to be validated

   $.get("check.php?id=" + id, function(result)
   {  
        if(result == 1) 
        {
           var $myForm = $("#myForm");

            //if the result is 1 submit.
            $myForm.submit();
        } 
        else 
        {  
            // dont submit, give some visual feedback, etc...
        }  
   });
```

}

Comment: Binding to the `submit` event is the better way to do it. If you use an mobile browser such as `iOS` it will allow you to submit using it's own UI `Submit` button on the keyboard, thus avoiding your button, and the validation. Some browsers also submit a form when the return key is pressed. The purpose of the `submit` event is to control validation.

Comment: @Scott Your correct my solution would be an incorrect in design if your supporting mobile platform. With that being said the user could only bypass the button if an input of type submit is present in the form. Since in my example I don't have any input of type submit the ios keyboard button would not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As your example requires that the OP avoids `<input type="submit" />` in favour of `<button></button>` to prevent the submission issues on mobile platforms, it is not as you have pointed out a suitable cross platform solution; You are also then putting unnecessary design constraints on the OP. Unless told otherwise it's best to assume they also want support for mobile platforms too. As such it cannot be touted as `the best solution is for you`; Your answer promotes bad practices, until it is updated more suitably I can't remove my downvote.

Comment: @Scott Agreed,  it was poor choice of words on my part.

Answer (score -1):

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
                checkInputData();
                //return false;  // to prevent default submit <-- THIS IS WRONG


                e.preventDefault(); //Try this :)
            });
        });
```

Returning false will prevent it from submitting in all cases.

Comment: This isn't really explaining what's going wrong. Add a description of what you changed, not just some "this is wrong" code comments